# Generic vs. Specific 'This' & 'That' type Questions

Tags: discussion

Recently, there's been a tendency to post an entire batch of questions in quick succession.

e.g. '(word) with' vs. '(word) at' (cf. [“Employment with” vs. “employment at”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/34162/14666) and its siblings).

This is not just similar to the "Possible Duplicate" syndrome; it could be worse in some cases.

Should we answer each of these individually at all?
Could we have a mechanism to merge them into a single generic question?
Should we advise posters to avoid the practice?

Comment: The batch has been bumped in quick succession because of retagging. It hasn't been posted in quick succession, though. Some of those posts are two days old; others, two years. And they are all by different posters, too. However, one of the reasons *why* they got retagged is indeed to simplify hunting for and closing of dupes. Most of the with-vs-at questions are closely related; a single generic question would be nice indeed. And there are at least three open questions about "in university" vs. "at university"; closing and/or merging would make sense.

Comment: @RegDwighт Thanks you so much for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

> Should we answer each of these individually at all?

If you think a question is a duplicate, vote to close it. Related questions are not closed as duplicates, though.

> Could we have a mechanism to merge them into a single generic question?

Questions that could be possibly merged are the ones that are exactly duplicates. For related/similar questions, we could create a canonical question used to answer similar/related questions, where the answer is used as comprehensive answer for any related question, when creating such question is possible, or worth doing it. Merging [a question asking about saying *working for*/*working at*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34162/employment-with-vs-employment-at) with [a question about *working at*/*working in*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8656/which-one-is-more-correct-works-at-a-university-or-works-in-a-university) would not make much sense.

> Should we advise posters to avoid the practice?

What we can do is pointing the OP to the duplicate question, when a duplicate question exists; in the other cases, we can point to any related question. Apart that, I don't think we can say to the askers not to ask a question because is related to another question already asked.